# WSO2 get api list SOAP request

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a problem with WSO2 Api Manager 1.7 SOAP API.
I have registered many tenants in my Api Manager and I have created many API for each and I have created an API for carbon super admin (tenant -1234).
I have created a web service client from this wsdl url `https://<.AM_IP>:<.AM_PORT>/services/API?wsdl` with wsimport command line (Axis2).

If I call `getAPIArtifactIDs` operation with Carbon Tenant admin credentials  i can get the api artifact id list.
If I call `getAPIArtifactIDs` operation with another tenant credentials  I have the empty list.
How I can resolve this problem?

This is my code:

```
System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "wso2carbon.jks");<br>
System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");<br>
System.getProperties().setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");<br>

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
});

API api = new API();
APIPortType port = api.getAPIHttpsSoap11Endpoint();
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;

bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://<.AM_IP>:<.AM_PORT>/services/API.APIHttpsSoap11Endpoint");<br>
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "admin");<br>
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "admin");<br>
List<String> ids = port.getAPIArtifactIDs();
if(ids!=null && !ids.isEmpty())
    for(String id : ids)
        System.out.println(id);
```

Comment: Can you try with soapui client , verify that you get the response with tenant clients . if it works with soapui client then need to check your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are need to retrieve the tenant information you have to use the tenant service register for that. The following is the WSDL URL for your tenant to retrieve API details.

https://<AM_IP>:<AM_PORT>/t/<TENANT_DOMAIN>/services/API?wsdl

But again if you need to get all APIs in API Manager way you can use the REST service which describes in [API Manager Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-GetAllAPIs).